# How to detect which disk my kernel booted from?

Tags: linux, shell-script, kernel, embedded

How could I detect from an early initramfs Linux shell script which bootable disk my kernel has booted from, especially when an identical(-ish) system could be installed on multiple disks?

The use-case is for dynamic logic to determine where to mount non-boot partitions as a replacement for a static `/etc/fstab`, so looking at that file or the output of `mount` is not an option...

To get even more specific, if an RPi disk image was written to both the SD/MMC card and a USB flash drive, how could that system determine which kernel was running? The RPi boot-loader controls boot disk order, and the same `root=/mmcblk0p2` kernel parameter can be used in either case, for whatever combination of RPi reasons. Does the `/proc/cmdline` contents get updated with the actual detected kernel root?

[Edit]

It looks like the RPi boot-loader does prepend some kernel parameters, but doesn't seem to touch the `root=` parameter, so no luck with `/proc/cmdline`.

This still might be a "generic" problem with any initramfs-only system, in which case the `root=` parameter is pretty meaningless anyway, since the root filesystem is the in a device-less ram image.

I happened across [this excellent related blog post at Bootlin.com](https://bootlin.com/blog/find-root-device/), and tried `stat /`, which yielded a "Device" of 02h, which decodes to a major device number of zero... and the docs at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt say that is for "Unnamed devices (e.g. non-device mounts)"

If my vague understanding of the kernel boot process is right, then the kernel couldn't actually know from whence it came, since it all got loaded into memory by the boot-loader.

All that said, I think I'm out of luck, without finding and parsing some more in-depth boot-loader-specific things.

Comment: I dont know if this will work during an early initramfs shell, but the 2nd line of `/var/log/boot.log*` shows the disk I'm booting from: `sudo sed -n '2p' /var/log/boot.log.1`

Comment: Your final understanding is correct : the kernel does not care a damn about where it comes from and why. The only one aware of that is… the bootloader. So the only possibility would be to use a bootloader that writes the info into whatever place the kernel could access later. AFAIK neither lilo nor grub do that.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you use UUID, LABEL or PARTUUID (for GPT disks) to find and mount the partitions.

Comment: In addition to my preceding comment, it seems that Das U-Boot https://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/ could do that. (I did not try though)